# SimpleXML : any element matching

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I need to parse an XML element that may have multiple format, depending on user needs. This format is implemented as "**any**" element in the XSD.

I have found that it is possible to do it with **JAXB** with `@XmlAnyElement` annotation :

```java
@XmlAnyElement
protected List<Element> any;
```

But I would like to know how do it using **Simple Xml framework**. Is it possible ? Will I need to mix both JAXB and SimpleXml ?

Here is the same question on Simple support : http://ehc.ac/p/simple/mailman/message/33015962/

Answer (score 2):

SimpleXml has the `Element*Union` feature exactly for this use case. Have a look at the following, which maps a list of interface `Result` to either the Result1 or Result2 implementation:

```
@Root(name = "response", strict = false)
public class Response {

    @ElementListUnion({
            @ElementList(inline = true, type = Result1.class, required=false),
            @ElementList(inline = true, type = Result2.class, required=false)
    })
    private @Nullable List<Result> resultList;

...
```

SimpleXml tries and binds one or the other implementation, that is why it is advisable to have a common interface for your getters. Of course you still need to write a model which matches with the xml in input in some way, but the union can help to reduce heterogeneous data input to your business/software domain.

Comment: Thank you Andrea for your help. I really need the "any" element because the input XML may contain any element (it models parameters). For now I can only use `strict = false` and grab information with Java XML but not with pure SimpleXML...

Comment: No problem! If I had control of the server side code I guess I would restrict the parameter format in order to get better support for XML/Java static type checking. But if this cannot be achieved I think you don't have other options.